# Determine consecutive date count in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have some data that looks like this:

```
id     date
--------------------------------
123    2013-04-08 00:00:00.000
123    2013-04-07 00:00:00.000
123    2013-04-06 00:00:00.000
123    2013-04-04 00:00:00.000
123    2013-04-03 00:00:00.000
```

I need to return a count of the most recent consecutive date streak for a given ID, which in this case would be `3` for id `123`. I have no idea if this can be done in SQL. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

The way to do this is to subtract a sequence of numbers and take the difference.  This is a constant for a sequence of dates.  Here is an example to get the length of all sequences for an id:

```
select id, grp, count(*) as NumInSequence, min(date), max(date)
from (select t.*,
             (date - row_number() over (partition by id order by date)) as grp
      from data t
     ) t
group by id, grp
```

To get the longest one, I would use `row_number()` again:

```
select t.*
from (select id, grp, count(*) as NumInSequence,
             min(date) as mindate, max(date) as maxdate,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   (date - row_number() over (partition by id order by date)) as grp
            from data t
           ) t
      group by id, grp
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```